# load webapp's button at the end of page load?

Tags: jquery, web-applications, button

I am developing [that website](http://www.bunch-it.com) and I have the problem that my buttons on the result page, firstly loaded as ordinary html buttons than they are shaped by jquery button function that I used. Is there any solution to show these button as shaped from the beginning? May be I can hide them up to end of the page load?

Comment: yes hide it and on document ready show the element and call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the jquery function as soon as your body is loaded. or use jquery [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
   shape_box(); //your box shaping function
});
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There fastest way is to check what style classes jquery applies to your buttons in their default state and then add those same classes yourself to the html-templates.  This works also for any other jquery-styled elements.